# Managed file: the file used in the field may not be referenced

Tags: 7, forms, files

I am having some issues with the [managed_file](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) type. Whenever I try to edit and save a form that has a managed_file element in it an error occurs: *The file  used in the Picture field may not be referenced.*

This is the code I'm using:

```
function foo_form ($form, &$form_state, $foo) {  
  ...     
  $form['file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Picture'),
    '#default_value' => (isset($foo->file->fid) ? $banner->foo->fid : ''),
    '#upload_location' => variable_get('foo_upload_location'),
  );

  if (isset($foo->file)) {
    $form['current_file'] = array(
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => $foo->file->fid,
    );
  }
  ...
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );
  return $form;
 }

function foo_form_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
  $foo = (object)$form_state['values'];

  $current_file_set = isset($form_state['values']['current_file']);

  if ($form_state['values']['file'] != 0 && !$current_file_set) {
    // Load the file uploaded in the form.
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['file']);

    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

    file_save($file);

    $foo->file = $file->fid;
  } else if ($form_state['values']['file'] != 0 && $current_file_set) {

    // If we are uploading a different picture, delete the old one and save the
    // new one. If not, don't do anything.
    if ($form_state['values']['current_file'] != $form_state['values']['file']) {
      file_delete(file_load($form_state['values']['current_file']));
      // Load the file uploaded in the form.
      $file = file_load($form_state['values']['file']);

      $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

      file_save($file);

      $foo->file = $file->fid;
    }
  } else {
    file_delete(file_load($form_state['values']['current_file']));
    $foo->file = null;
  }

  ...
}
```

I traced the error back to the [file_managed_file_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--file--file.module/function/file_managed_file_validate/7) function in *modules/file/file.module* but don't know anything about the file references.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solution is to add a call to [file_usage_add](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_usage_add/7) after the file is saved. This call adds a reference to the file in the database. The [file_managed_file_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--file--file.module/function/file_managed_file_validate/7) function will spot the reference and won't trigger the error.

```
file_usage_add($file, 'foo', 'foo', $foo->id);
```

This isn't documented in the [Form API under the managed_file example](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file).

This issue is being discussed on the Drupal documentation issues: [link](http://drupal.org/node/979158)

Comment: +1 Just been tearing my hair our over this, adding a file usage record solves the problem immediately. Thank you!

Comment: Thankfully it is now added to the managed_file example.  But it wasn't in whatever example I'd followed so this answer was a lifesaver!

Comment: @Clive What is about saving files from template settings?! There is no module to act as parameter in that function!

Comment: @sємsєм just use the name of the theme - the string itself isn't validated, it just needs to be something unique to the thing that's tracking it - module name is used for namespacing all over Drupal so that's the convention that stuck

Comment: @Clive Could you please get a look at this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124373/uploaded-images-in-theme-settings-is-going-to-be-lost